# Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object:

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-testing

I've been trying to write a test using the following code:

```
class ViewTestCase(TestCase):
 def setUp(self):
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(first_name='tester',
        username='test1', 
        password='123', 
        email='testuser@something.com')

 def test_room_creation(self):
    c = Client()
    payload = {"titlePlanning": "Teste1","styleCards": "Fibonnaci","deck": ["1","2","3"]}
    c.login(username='test1',password='123')
    request = c.post('/room', payload, content_type='application/json')
    response = BeginRoom.as_view()(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    print(request)
```

the view that I'm testing needs the following data:

```
class BeginRoom(APIView):
permissions_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    data= self.request.data
    user = request.user
    name = data['titlePlanning'].strip()
    styleCards = data['styleCards']
    cards = data['deck']
```

This is the Model that the view access to do the POST:

```
class PokerRoom(models.Model):

status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=STATUS, verbose_name=_('status')
name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name=_('name of the room'))
styleCards = MultiSelectField(choices=CHOICES, default=FIBONACCI)    
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
deck = models.ForeignKey(Pack, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
active_story = models.OneToOneField('Story', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,verbose_name=_('active_storys'), 
related_name='active_in',
null=True)
```

My problem is that whenever I run my test I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 
0x7fbfb77ca3d0>": "PokerRoom.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

I thought that I only needed to login with my user and after that it would be instantiated but its not working. Can someone help me?

Edit1: Trying to use APIClient instead of Client as suggested, but still getting the same error unfortunately

```
    c = APIClient()
    payload = {"titlePlanning": "Teste1","styleCards": "Fibonnaci","deck": ["1","2","3"]}
    login = c.login(username='test1',password='123')
    self.assertTrue(login)
    request = c.post('/room', payload, format='json')

ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7fcbc3c06b20>": "PokerRoom.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Comment: check whether you have a user with username 'test1' or not.

Comment: print(User.objects.get(username='test1')) is giving me .test1 so I guess its exists

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Django REST Framework with that `APIView`? I don't have experience with it but they have their own `APIClient` that you might want to be using instead of Django's `Client`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#authenticating

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately